# Is it possible to use InstallShield to install more than one .exe files?

Tags: perl, postgresql, embed, executable, installshield

I have completed a project on VisualStudio and I have built the .exe file of this project. I wanted to make an installer that will include this .exe file as well as the postgreSQL and perl executable installers because my VB application relies on them to work. So I assume that if I want it to work properly on every windows-based PC I have to include those as well.

Is there a way I can include those 3 .exe(s) in a single setup (let's say .MSI file) and if yes what are the steps required to do so?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
George.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MSI shouldn't ever run an EXE installer.  For that scenario you need what's called a bootstrapper / chainer.   The two are similar except that boostrapper is things that must be installed before your MSI ( like Windows Installer itself ) and chainer are things that get installed along with your MSI.

InstallShield has two features for this.  Setup / Feature Prerequisites and Suite Installers.  Both can be used to chain together any number of EXE and MSI installers.

For more information see:

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)